# Storing and returning emojis

Tags: sql, oracle, unicode, emoji

What's the simplest way to write and, then, read `Emoji` symbols in `Oracle` table?

Currently I have this situation:

- `iOS` client pass encoded `Emojis`: `One%20more%20time%20%F0%9F%98%81%F0%9F%98%94%F0%9F%98%8C%F0%9F%98%92`. For example, `%F0%9F%98%81` means ;
- Column type is `nvarchar2(2000)`, so when view saved text via `Oracle SQL Developer` it looks like: `One more time ????????`.

Comment: So what is your goal? To show one specific symbol instead of `%F0%9F%98%81` or to show an emoji image (the last one is hardly possible I think)?

Comment: The goal is to get the same data from table, which were written into it previously.

Comment: To get the same data in which program? Sure you are aware that `????????` is just matter of character encoding settings. Is it `One%20more%20time%20%F0%9F%98%81%F0%9F%98%94%F0%9F%98%8C%F0%9F%98%92` string that should be displayed in SQL Developer or something else? Please post the required result.

Comment: Yes. `One%20more%20time%20%F0%9F%98%81%F0%9F%98%94%F0%9F%98%8C%F0%9F%98%92` was stored (http encoded string) and it should be returned.

Comment: The 4 bytes hex `F09F9881` is the UTF-8 encoding for ``.

Comment: Nothing new here. Read the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, we do `BASE64` encoding/decoding of the text. It’s suitable for small texts.

Answer (score 0):

This seems more a client problem than a database problem. Certain iOs programs are capable of interpreting that string and show an image instead of that string.

SQL Developer does not do that.

As long as the data stored in the database is the same as the data retrieved from the database, you have no problem.

Comment: Not exactly. Data stored to database `One%20more%20time%20%F0%9F%98%81%F0%9F%98%94%F0%9F%98%8C%F0%9F%98%92` and data retrieve from database is `One more time ????????`.

Comment: Show us the code to you use to insert the data into the database.

Comment: I cannot show the code, yet you could be sure that http encoded data like `%20%F0%9F%98%81` converts into unicode smiles.

Answer (score -1):

In MySQL the character set needs to be set to UTF-16 to be able to save emojis, I assume Oracle would need the same ch

Comment: Unless you know for sure, this is better suited for a comment than an answer.  You will have to wait for some reputation score to comment.

Comment: No.  Use utf8mb4 for Emoji in MySQL.